# If module did not create properly then remove data from which tables for reinstall the module in vtiger

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

am new in vtiger. Could anyone tell me which tables are store for module related data? Suppose I create a module ABC for any purpose. Then it will create two tables (1) vtiger_ABC and (2) vtiger_ABCcf and vtiger_crm is common. My questions are

1) without this three tables which tables are required extra.

2) If module did not create properly then remove data from which tables for reinstall the module in vtiger7. Please tell me the tables name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Those three tables are the only ones strictly needed (vtiger_yourmodule, vtiger_yourmodulecf and vtiger_crmentity). Of course you could create additional tables, but only if you have a special need. For basic entity modules you only need those three.

2) you should run a script for module uninstallation:

```
<?php 
require_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

$MODULENAME = 'yourmodule';

$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);
if ($moduleInstance) {
    echo "Module is present - deleting module instance...\n";
    $moduleInstance->delete();
} else {
    echo "Module not found...\n";
}
```

put it on your vtiger root folder and execute it through a browser. That script will delete some entries in some other tables. You can also manually delete tables vtiger_yourmodule and vtiger_yourmodulecf and delete your module's folder in vtiger_root/modules/yourmodule